# Travelling to Yerevan from Delhi through flydubai

Tags: visas, bookings, transit-visas, airlines, flydubai

I am confused about the ok to board requirements because since I will be getting armenian evisa and my flight which is flydubai airlines from delhi to yerevan will have stop over at dubai , then what is ok to board requirements for me and how should i obtain this ok to board requirements. Besides is it possible to obtain stamped armenian visa for indian nationals since on their site i could only find evisa or visa on arrival option.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Flydubai has on their website regarding the "OK to Fly" requirements. "When you've paid for your booking, you can contact a local Flydubai office or one of the Flydubai travel shops in UAE, India or Pakistan (depending on where your visa is being processed) for the approval. Nominal charges will apply. Operating hours for Flydubai local offices may vary." You can get more information at Flydubai's website here: https://www.flydubai.com/en/flying-with-us.